# Locally Dedcodable Codes and Private Information Retrieval

Tags: pir

Does anyone know about Locally Decodable Codes (LDCs)? It seems the private information retrieval schemes that based on LDCs are computationally efficent (answer a query without processing the whole database). Why LDCs receives little attention in cryptographic world?

Comment: What is your question? PIR should hide an index in the query, while LDC needs not. There's a (little) gap.

Comment: @xagawa Why LDC not? LDC only reveal the index in the codewords instead of the real storage.